# Error al crear ArrayBidimencional

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo el buscaminas con tamaños que se introduce mediante el teclado(o botones en android que los tamaños son 8-12-16) pero el tablero esta mal creado , me crea bombas donde no deberia o los numeros de al lado de las bombas estan mal.
El tablero de 8x8 me lo hace bien pero luego no
Creo que el error esta en este for pero no consigo verlo

```
for (int f2 = max(0, f - 1); f2 < min(TAM, f + 2); f2++) {
                for (int c2 = max(0, c - 1); c2 < min(TAM, c + 2); c2++) {
```

Aqui os dejo el codigo del tablero

```
public void setTablero() {

        for (int f = 0; f < TAM ; f++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < TAM ; c++) {
                tablero[f][c] = 0;

                System.out.println(TAM);
            }
        }


        //Pone diez minas
        for (int mina = 0; mina < minas; mina++) {
            //Busca una posición aleatoria donde no haya otra bomba
            int f, c;
            do {
                Random rand = new Random();
                f = rand.nextInt(TAM);
                c = rand.nextInt(TAM);
            } while (tablero[f][c] == -1);
            //Pone la bomba
            tablero[f][c] = -1;
            //Recorre el contorno de la bomba e incrementa los contadores
            for (int f2 = max(0, f - 1); f2 < min(TAM, f + 2); f2++) {
                for (int c2 = max(0, c - 1); c2 < min(TAM, c + 2); c2++) {
                    if (tablero[f2][c2] != -1) { //Si no es bomba
                        tablero[f2][c2]++; //Incrementa el contador
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int f = 0; f < TAM; f++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < TAM; c++) {
                System.out.println(tablero[f][c]);
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Como bien indicas, ese for no tiene buena pinta... No entiendo del todo porqué usas "min(TAM, f + 2)" para los length de los for. ya que tienes la variable "TAM" del principio. ¿Puedes mostrarnos el resultado de como queda la vista que te pinta las bombas mal puestas?

Comment: https://imgur.com/fmqaAi9 Lo que pasa es que me cuenta mal las bombas de alrededor